# Statistical Distance that doesn't require absolute continuity

Tags: statistics, absolute-continuity

I was going through Kullback–Leibler divergence and it was mentioned in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) article that it requires **absolute continuity**. It was written that ***The Kullback–Leibler divergence is defined only if for all $x$, $Q ( x ) = 0$  implies  $P(x)=0$ (absolute continuity)***. However, I am trying to find a statistical distance that doesn't follow this type of conditions. Thus, $Q(x)$ can be $0$ even though $P(x)$ is not. Is there any type of statistical distance possible without that condition?

Comment: You could consider any of the distances that metrize the weak topology.  For instance, the [Lévy–Prokhorov metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric).

Comment: @Nate what do you mean by weak topology?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures